# How to install DevStack when firewall blocks git

Tags: git, firewall, openstack

I have been following the guide at https://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/ but always errors:

```
...
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:718:git_clone
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:538:git_timed
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:602:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:602 git call failed: [git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements --branch master]
Error on exit
./stack.sh: line 506: generate-subunit: command not found
stack@DevStack:~/devstack$
```

So I tried the last command (`git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements --branch master`) manually and got:

```
Cloning into '/opt/stack/requirements'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.openstack.org:
git.openstack.org[0: 104.130.246.128]: errno=Connection timed out
git.openstack.org[1: 2001:4800:7819:103:be76:4eff:fe06:63c]: errno=Network is unreachable
```

I think this is due to using `git://` instead of `http://` because when I try replacing it, I get:

```
stack@DevStack:~/devstack$ git clone http://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements --branch master
Cloning into '/opt/stack/requirements'...
remote: Counting objects: 18929, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9696/9696), done.
remote: Total 18929 (delta 12803), reused 15154 (delta 9213)
Receiving objects: 100% (18929/18929), 2.83 MiB | 2.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12803/12803), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
stack@DevStack:~/devstack$
```

I assume this is because I am behind a restrictive company firewall. So how do I get the setup script to use http instead of git?

Answer (score 1):

In the cloned repository edit [line 228](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/fbdefacc1d7be98d9b34a2fb7f35aada33611604/stackrc#L228) in the `stackrc` file. You can easily replace the `git://` by `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am pretty sure this isn't the best way, but using a combination of the answers from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-to-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392478/how-to-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux-command-line

I used `grep -rlnw '/opt/stack/' -e 'git:' | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/git:/http:/g' @` to replace the `git://` with `http://`.

However, since the install keeps downloading more files with `git://`, then I needed to run this simultaneously during the install in order to replace as new files were downloaded:

`watch -n 1 grep -rlnw '/opt/stack/' -e 'git:' | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/git:/http:/g' @`